# How can I make Pandas read my csv file proparly because it now puts every value into the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter

I have a question about pandas. I am trying to open the raw_fighter_details.csv file on this kaggle page: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rajeevw/ufcdata?select=raw_fighter_details.csv via pandas in Jupyter Notebook.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/jimwe_/OneDrive/Bureaublad/raw_fighter_details.csv")
df.head()
```

It is not opening correctly. All the seperate columns have been made such as: fighter_name, Height and Weight but it is putting all the data in the rows below into the fighter_name column.

It is however correctly opening another csv file. The one on this kaggle page: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction

Does anyone know why the first file is not opening correctly and if so do you have a solution?

Comment: Works for me to download it and use your code. The values are correctly put into fields. Did you open the file in some other program beforehand and modify it? Such as Excel which might convert the separators, change the encoding or similar. (Or as might be concluded from the file path did you upload it to OneDrive and open it there which could modify it as well.)

Comment: Yes, I opened it in Excel. I'll try downloading it again. Thx for the help.

Comment: Thanks It worked! You just saved my entire project!

Answer (score 1):

From the first link https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rajeevw/ufcdata?select=raw_fighter_details.csv

I've downloaded the zip file (4MB), and extracted "raw_fighter_details.csv", but there seems to be no problem

[image]

Comment: ewz93 found the anwser. Apperently if you first open the file in excel it changes it and pandas can't open it correctly.

Comment: that's great! I've looked through some of @ewz93's answers and upvoted them, they are very good also.. I must learn from him!